# Not able to add UILocalNotification multiple time

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I am trying to add UILocalNotification in a loop with different date like for week. When i add fire date not changing. Below is my code, please help me to fixe this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
BOOL isTimer = NO;
for(i=1;i<8;i++){    
 NSDate *date = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*i];    
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; //Create the localNotification object

    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    NSLog(@"user date time before firing %@",date);
    [localNotification setFireDate:(isTimer?[NSDate getDateFromString:[NSDate getEndDateTime:timeInt]]:date)];
    NSLog(@"notification fire date %@",localNotification.fireDate);

    //Set the date when the alert will be launched using the date adding the time the user selected on the timer
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open"]; //The button's text that launches the application and is shown in the alert
    [localNotification setAlertBody:titleHeader]; //Set the message in the notification from the textField's text
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [localNotification setHasAction: YES]; //Set that pushing the button will launch the application
    [localNotification setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:@"title",titleHeader,@"url",link, nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    localNotification = nil;
}
```

Below is the log

```
user date time before firing 2015-06-10 05:22:00 +0000
notification fire date 2015-06-10 16:11:14 +0000

user date time before firing 2015-06-11 05:22:00 +0000
notification fire date 2015-06-10 16:11:19 +0000

user date time before firing 2015-06-12 05:22:00 +0000
notification fire date 2015-06-10 16:12:34 +0000

user date time before firing 2015-06-13 05:22:00 +0000
notification fire date 2015-06-10 16:12:38 +0000

user date time before firing 2015-06-14 05:22:00 +0000
notification fire date 2015-06-10 16:12:39 +0000

user date time before firing 2015-06-15 05:22:00 +0000
notification fire date 2015-06-10 16:12:39 +0000

user date time before firing 2015-06-16 05:22:00 +0000
notification fire date 2015-06-10 16:12:39 +0000
```

Comment: it is logging as same date.      user date time before firing 2015-06-10 05:22:00 +0000
notification fire date 2015-06-10 16:11:14 +0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `isTimer` is true, so you are using the same date over and over; your `date` variable is different each time thru the loop, but it is never used.

Comment: isTimer is false every time.

Comment: No it isn't. If it were, the fire dates would match your `date`.

Comment: Your `date` is advancing one day each time, as you expect. The fire date is not. Your `date` is not being used to set the fire date. The logging proves it.

Comment: Thanks a lot matt, it is my mistake isTimer is true every time.